# Can I use a recessed subpanel in the wall between house and attached garage?

Tags: garage, subpanel

I am planning to install a subpanel in my attached garage, with most likely a 70A feed from the main panel.  Can the subpanel be the recessed type that fits in the wall cavity between 2 studs, in the frame wall that separates the house from the garage?  Where I want to put the subpanel, the other side of the wall on the house side is a closet.  If I can, can batt insulation still be used around the subpanel in that wall cavity?

Comment: Does that wall need to be fire-rated by your local code?

Comment: @JonCuster - I'll need to inquire, there is fire-rated drywall on the garage side.

Comment: You probably cannot fit _both_ a panel _and_ insulation in the stud bay in the wall separating house from garage. The wall is probably not deep enough to have both.

Comment: @FreeMan - Agreed.  I was thinking more about the wall cavity space above and below the recessed box since the hole for the box would break the continuous sheet of fire-code drywall.

Comment: You'll probably regret recessing it, when you ever want to add circuits later.  Also 70A is a very tiny panel, I recommend a *much* larger panel so you are flexible to deal with future expansion.  Spaces are cheap.  Especially don't skimp on spaces while overspending on copper wire - aluminum is fine, #4 is good for 65A and #2 is good for 90A.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica - I've spent considerable amount of time trying to find out what size conduit I need for 2-2-2-4 SER Al cable for the 5 feet the cable is run on the garage wall up to the sub panel.  All the online calculators use WIRE count and type.  And I have found at least 2 different ODs for 2-2-2-4 SER Al cable, from .956 to .973.  Suggestions?

Comment: @user149104 take the worst case OD and multiply by 138%.  Or if the whole run is in continuous conduit anyway, and it's built properly so it can be pulled, you can use individual wires of THHN or XHHW type.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you can put a panel in a plastered wall in a closet. You may regret the choice if the closet makes getting to the panel difficult, the fiberglass insulation is also OK. Since you don’t know too much about power it might be better if you avoid aluminum wire. Scrubbing in no-Al-ox and torquing connections correctly isn’t that difficult but getting it wrong can cause expensive damage.